# Passing a value on SelectedIndexChange

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, eventargs

My page currently looks like this:

```
<!-- Datasource -->

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_GetURL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEST_DEV1 %>" SelectCommand="TEST_GetReports" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">  
    <SelectParameters> 

        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="UserId" Type="String" />

    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<!-- Dropdown List -->

Company: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanyList" 
runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_GetURL" 
DataValueField="RSReportLinkID" DataTextField="ReportName" CssClass="select">

</asp:DropDownList>

<!-- Report Viewer -->

 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Width="930px" Height="1000" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="/Systems/Test/Report 1" ReportServerUrl="http://test/ReportServer" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

The code behind it is:

```
protected void ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //TODO: change to SP   
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.ConnectionStringName].ConnectionString;
    string strCustomerID = CommonCode.GetCurrentCustomerID();
    string strUserID = CommonCode.GetCurrentUserID().ToString();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("TEST_GetReportSettingsForReport", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", strCustomerID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", strUserID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RSReportLinkID", "5CCD639D-E930-4896-AE36-323EC3495D24");
;


        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Response.Write(reader.GetValue(3));

            }
        }

        else
        {
           /* Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");*/
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }


 }
```

Currently @RSReportLinkID is hard coded to be 5CCD639D-E930-4896-AE36-323EC3495D24, so when a report is selected via the drop down, ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged will do it's magic and return the ReportPath from the fourth column of my table thanks to this line:

```
Response.Write(reader.GetValue(3));
```

My question however is, how can I pass a ReportLinkID to @RSReportLinkID instead of hard coding one? The options in my dropdown list are being fed through from a stored procedure that grabs a list of reports from a table. Each report also has a ReportLinkID in the first column, so I am hoping just to do something such as... When a report is selected from the drop down which would be a SelectedIndexChange, the first column from my table is grabbed (which will be the ReportLinkID) and this is then passed onto my code and stored in @RSReportLinkID.

Thanks for any help or information! I have a feeling that this is something very simple that will involve the use of object sender and EventArgs e, however I am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to store RSReportLinkID as the value of the dropdownlist. That way in the ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged method you will be able to access it like this:

```
protected void ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    string RSReportLinkID = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris! I knew it would be something ridiculously simple... Works like a charm.